# URLs break compilation

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, urls

Just as a preamble, I use MikTex 2.8, the latest TeXworks for Windows, the natbib, hyperref, and pdftex packages, JabRef to manage my citations, and the pdfLatex option in TeXworks for compilation.

Everything works correctly and as expected -- unless I include the URL of an electronic paper I am citing. Then, compilation crashes, with the following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.321 ....com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1697352}
```

Here is the minimal example which generates this error:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}
\usepackage[pdftex,
        urlcolor=rltblue,       % \href{...}{...} external (URL)
        filecolor=rltgreen,     % \href{...} local file
        linkcolor=rltred,       % \ref{...} and \pageref{...}
        citecolor=black,
        colorlinks=true,
        hypertexnames=false,
        bookmarks=true,
        bookmarksnumbered=true,
        bookmarksopen=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

Testing. \cite{Shor:2011all}

\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\bibliography{testurl}

\end{document}
```

The `testurl.bib` file, includes the item in question this way:

```
@ELECTRONIC{Shor:2011all,
  author = {Boris Shor},
  year = {2011},
  title = {All Together Now: Putting Congress, State Legislatures, and Individuals
    in a Common Ideological Space to Assess Representation at the Macro
    and Micro Levels},
  url = {http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1697352},
  owner = {Boris},
  timestamp = {2010.04.04}
}
```

As you can see, it references the url of the electronic document (unpublished paper) I am trying to cite from SSRN: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1697352

The generated .bbl file contains the following item:

```
\harvarditem{Shor}{2011}{Shor:2011all}
Shor, Boris. 2011.
\newblock ``All Together Now: Putting Congress, State Legislatures, and
  Individuals in a Common Ideological Space to Assess Representation at the
  Macro and Micro Levels.''.
\newline\harvardurl{http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1697352}
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Is the issue the underscore in the url?

Comment: Hmmmm. Interesting. When I switch the underscore to a dash, the paper compiles correctly. BUT -- the url DOES include an underscore! :) Also -- perhaps you can move your comment to an answer, because I think you're on to it and I'd like to give you the credit.

Comment: @bshor: don't know what hardvard does, but write into your document: `\usepackage{url} \let\harvardurl\url`

Comment: When I put "\usepackage{url}\let\harvardurl\url" into the preamble, I get "Command \harvardurl already defined." I am using the natbib package (no options) and the pdftex package. Perhaps natbib already calls harvardurl?

Comment: Create a small example file ...

Comment: @Herbert I just did to the post above. Thanks.

Comment: When I run BibTeX, I get `Warning--entry type for "Shor:2011all" isn't style-file defined`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you use `hyperref`, you don't need to load the `url` package. After loading `hyperref`, you could redefine `\harvardurl`:

```
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}
```

Orignally, `natbib` defines it by

```
\newcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL:} \textit{#1}}
```

This definition doesn't work with underscores in the argument. `\url` fixes it. If you would like to have italic urls, you could achieve that for example by

```
\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\itshape}
```

Comment: The renewcommand fixed it! Awesome. What an odd default for natbib, though, to crack on underscores in URLs!