# Cannot display tilde (~) in references latex / BibLatex

Tags: natbib, urls

I have a link to a URL looking like this

```
http://www.abc.de/~doo/bar/foobar.htm
```

As you can see, it contains a `~`. I tried changing the link to

```
http://www.abc.de/\~doo/bar/foobar.htm
```

However, the `~` goes over the `d`, something like `ñ`. How can I display the tilde properly?

That is the file entry

```
@webpage{rajapakse2008,
    Author = {Rajapakse, Damith C.},
    Date-Added = {2018-01-25 14:31:33 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-05-03 21:05:13 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {25.01.2018},
    Month = {04},
    Title = {Fragmentation of Mobile Applications},
    Url = {http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/\~damithch/df/device-fragmentation.htm},
    Year = {2008},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~damithch/df/device-fragmentation.htm}}
```

Comment: [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312/134574) might be useful. Although, for URLs you shouldn't need escaping, as BibLaTeX buts them in a verbatim context automatically.

Comment: Can you show us the resulting `.bib` entry? If you indeed use `biblatex`, you should use the `url` field, that field is a special verbatim field where special characters need not (and should not!) be escaped. If you use BibTeX and must resort to `note` or `howpublished` you should look into wrapping your URLs in `\url{...}`.

Comment: @moewe added the entry to the question. I have to escape all special characters though...

Comment: OK, then we need to know what bibliography package (`cite`, `natbib`, `biblatex`, ...) and which style you use. The handling of URLs differs between `biblatex` (where things are largely handled uniformly) and BibTeX styles (with vastly varying degrees of support for URLs). Please consider adding a full MWE/MWEB that shows this.

Comment: @moewe I use `natbib` with a modified `agsm`, namely this one: https://gist.github.com/moewew/6c65c256c9420d64f3b264c0a78774c0 its yours :)

Comment: No wonder it doesn't work then .... Try `\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9445/35864)

Comment: @moewe I have that already in it `\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{[Online] URL: \textit{#1}}`

Comment: That's why we ask for [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)s on this site, that would have been an important bit of information. Try `\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{[Online] URL: \url{#1}}` then (if that produces an error you may have to load the `hyperref` or `url` package - depending on whether you like links in general or not).

Comment: @moewe Hm, I dont wanna use a `\url` in there. I use `\textasciitilde` as suggested by  Phelype Oleinik - that does the trick somewhat

Comment: Why do you not want to use `\url`? That command really is the simplest way to tell LaTeX that you are typesetting a URL. URLs require special treatment, so LaTeX normally botches them badly unless specifically told to handle it otherwise. If you don't like the fact that `url`/`hyperref` print URLs in typewriter font by default you can use [`\urlstyle` to change that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53962/35864).

Comment: To people of the future, a crude way to deal with this is to use $\sim$ everywhere you would have a tilde. E.g."http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/\$\sim$damithch/df/device-fragmentation.htm"