# How to remove this extra space before url in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, url

How do I remove this space please? I'm using the `natbib` package

[image: space before url]

Code from ref.bib

```
@article{stats2017,
  title={Digest of Education Statistics 2017},
  author={\text{Statistics Mauritius}},
  year={2017},
  url={\url{http://statsmauritius.govmu.org/English/Publications/Pages/Edu_Stats_Yr2017.aspx}}
}
```

bibliography style

```
%\printbibliography
\setcitestyle{numbers} % set the citation style to ``numbers''.
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{ref.bib}
```

Comment: The space printed there will also depend on the bibliography style (`\bibliographystyle`) your are using, so in order to help, you we would need to know about it. Please consider adding a complete example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) to tell us what you are doing. But URL breaking is a bit tricky and it certainly looks as though this URL is hard to fit into the available space if you only allow the standard break points.

Comment: you need to either add more break points for the url, or typeset the bibliography in \raggedright

Comment: It (probably) won't help with your issue, but the `author` should be given as `author={{Statistics Mauritius}},`, there is no need for `\text`, but you do want to pairs of curly braces (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864). Usually you don't have to include the `\url{...}` macro in the `url` field, so `url={http://statsmauritius.govmu.org/English/Publications/Pages/Edu_Stats_Yr2017.aspx},` should be enough. It could be that your style/bibliography package does not apply `\url` by default, but that can be changed (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9445/35864)

Comment: Hi Moewe.  I have added the bibligraphy style. in the main post.  With the '\text', it was not displaying properly.  As for the '\url' braces, i added it based on recommendation from earlier question.  The url was not printing properly and overflowing the page.

Comment: Some url are showing correctly with no whitespace before them.  There is an example in the image above. the first one is ok.  the second one has white space before.

Comment: As @UlrikeFischer has already pointed out, unless this is set `\raggedright` or another breakpoint is defined, the extra space isn't going to go away.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution, assuming your TeX distribution is reasonably up to date, consists of loading the `xurl` package; it allows arbritary line breaks in URL strings. Should your TeX distribution lack the `xurl` package, I suggest you (a) load the `url` package with the options `spaces` and `hyphens` and (b) switch to `\raggedright` right before `\bibliography{ref}`.

Whatever else you do, please encase the `author` field in an extra pair of curly braces. Doing so informs BibTeX that it's dealing with a "corporate" author and not with a person whose first name is "Statistics" and whose surname is "Mauritius". And do get rid of the `\text` wrapper too, as it is not appropriate here.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{stats2017,
  title  = "{Digest of Education Statistics 2017}",
  author = "{Statistics Mauritius}",
  year   = 2017,
  url    = "http://statsmauritius.govmu.org/English/Publications/Pages/Edu_Stats_Yr2017.aspx",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbers,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\renewcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL}: \url{#1}} % optional
\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks anywhere in URL string

\begin{document}
\cite{stats2017}
\bibliography{ref}  % not "\bibliography{ref.bib}"
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I cannot seem to be able to use the 'xurl' as i'm using overleaf.  I tried the second option, it worked but the ref does not look so good when its reggedright.